# Extract and Store javascript variable value inside script written inside executeScript to normal java variable

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In below-written code, I want to use the URL variable value inside the javascript written and I want to store it in String URL variable of java.

I tried to use the getParameter method but that is used in JSP. I tried to Search it elsewhere but everywhere the value extraction is explained through JSP. Please help. Is there any way other than JSP for using the value inside the script?

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\Browser Chrome Driver files\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    //WebDriver driver1 = null;
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
    js.executeScript("var url = prompt(\"URL\");");
    String url = request.getParameter("url");

2nd attempt:
When I use this code,

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\Browser Chrome Driver 
    files\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            //WebDriver driver1 = null;
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
            //String script = ;

        String url =(String)js.executeScript("var user = prompt(\"Enter your 
    name, please:\", \"https://myeg/login\");\r\n" + 
                "if (user != null) {\r\n" + 
                "    return user;\r\n" + 
                "}");



            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.get(url);
```

I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null. I want the URL to be accessed by the driver through javascript prompt. But getting null pointer exception on 2nd attempt.

Comment: You probably don't want to invoke a JavaScript prompt that will most likely trigger an UnhandledAlertException.

Comment: Please elaborate. I didn't get that.

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#user-prompts

Comment: @PratikPathare, could You  please share a bit more context here , and also point to the place in code where URL variable in defined (it should be defined as far I can see).

Comment: @eugene.polschikov URL is been defined inside the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I used java and succeeded. I imported javax.swing.JOptionPane library and created object of JOptionPane class. Then used showInput dialog method and I stored the value I put in that dialog in a variable. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return` in the JavaScript

```
String script = "var url = prompt(\"URL\");"
              + "return url;";

String url = (String)js.executeScript(script);
```

Comment: Not working. Getting the java.lang.NullPointerException exception.Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a) on port 25723
Only local connections are allowed.
Jul 18, 2019 5:23:37 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null

Comment: Using the above code, the driver.get(url) line gets null value. Hence null pointer exception is occured.